# Apache: LoadModule mod_wsgi-4.9.0 giving error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have installed mod_wsgi-4.9.0. On checking

```
ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

was giving error:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeb0967000)
        libpython3.9.so.1.0 => not found
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f34e36a9000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f34e348d000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f34e3289000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f34e3086000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f34e2d84000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f34e29b6000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f34e27b3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f34e3b1e000)
```

Then from somewhere I got to know LD_LIBRARY_PATH needs to exported and after doing:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
```

the error was gone.

Now I'm trying to start apache server:

```
systemctl start httpd
```

But its giving error as:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 361 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I kept the shared object libpython3.9.so.1.0 at path `/home/user/python3.9/lib/`
and tried modifying httpd.conf with SetEnv:

```
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/user/python3.9/lib
```

But still the error is same.

P.S.: I have 2 versions of python installed - 2.7 and 3.9
Python3.9 is installed at a particular path and have installed mod_wsgi corresponding to python3.9 . Default version of python is 2.7 in system.

Can somebody help please.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in ~/.bash_profile and restarted the machine